# Is there any legit way to play Diablo 2 on Battle.net with a higher resolution?

Tags: diablo-ii

The highest resolution that the game normally supports is 800x600. Is there anything I can do on Battle.net that's legal that will increase the resolution?

Comment: It looks like [there are ways to do it offline](https://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/21a41c/playing_diablo_2_again_try_this/), but online you might get banned for trying it.  It also looks like there are mods for it, but again its not legal for online likely.

Comment: You can probably do it using 3rd party online tools, since D2 is still a peer to peer game.  I'm not sure why doing this will get you banned, but I don't have details on how the anti-cheating detection works in D2 to begin with.

Comment: Are you trying to play on Battle.net? That will affect which options will work for you.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah that's my issue is I can't mod anything while I do online play

Comment: @ChaseC You are aware that you can play multiplayer using TCP/IP or a LAN without using Battle.net, correct? That's still playing "online", so I'm trying to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah no problem. Battle.net

Comment: @Nelson: My guess is that since higher resolution would allow you to see further (you can see to the edge of your window), it is considered an advantage, especially when playing PVP. You would be able to see others before they saw you.

Comment: Bots are rampant in D2 now. They won't ban you for a glide wrapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [a blue post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20742914494#post-10) regarding the resolution:

> As of right now we're focusing on compatibility and bug fixing for Diablo II. While a higher resolution would be awesome and on our radar, as of right now it's not top priority.

And another more [recent blue post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/bnet/topic/20752375753#post-6) with regards to whether the resolution will ever be increased:

> I won't say never but it's unlikely due to how much work it would require on such an older game.

The first blue post also stated:

> A Glide Wrapper would not a bannable offense.

So I guess you could use a Glide Wrapper to scale Diablo 2 to your desktop resolution (but it'll still be 800 x 600) to make it run smoother.